# SAX Parser - Handle escape characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri, saxparser

I use a SAX parser to parse an XML file in which one of the nodes is:

```
<product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=aLzfEdguEI4&amp;offerid=dsf5.67217798179</product>
```

My `characters` method currently returns the string as

```
http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=aLzfEdguEI4
```

instead of the full string

```
http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=aLzfEdguEI4&amp;offerid=dsf5.67217798179
```

The ampersand sign (`&amp;`) is taken as the escape character.

```
def characters(string)    
  string    
end
```

How is it possible to get the whole string. I need this using SAX parser, not with DOM.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We can't reproduce the problem.